# I've got a Syntax Error in FOREACH near Parameter name in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

So, let me start with saying that I'm a complete Noob when it comes to SQL.

Ive Got two tables within a Schema: Attributes and Skills.

I wanted to automatically add the Skills for Each Attribute, since I already got all their Names in the "Modifies" column of the Attributes table, and well, also their Attribute.

The Code for The Function is the Following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AddSkFromList(p_Attr "Cyberpunk2020"."Attr", p_SkList text[]) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    v_SkName text;
BEGIN
    FOREACH v_SkName IN p_SkList LOOP
        INSERT INTO "Cyberpunk2020"."Skills" ("Attribute", "Name")
        VALUES (p_Attr, v_SkName);


    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Which gives me the Syntax Error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "p_SkList"
LINE 5: FOREACH v_SkName IN p_SkList LOOP
                            ^
```

I sadly am unable to figure out why this function doesn't work, according to the Postgres Docs the FOREACH statement requires a target and an Expression, in all Examples I've found the target got Declared in the Declare Block [Duh], and the Expression can be any kind of Array. I've tried setting the p_SkList parameter to just text, but the error is the same. Do I fundamentally misunderstand something about Postgres and the array to loop over has to be predefined? I also set the search_path to the corrosponding Shema, in which I Want to create the Function, which is the same one that houses the Tables, and as you can see below, I'm able to access the tables with a simple `\d+ $shema_name`

The Attributes Table looks Like the Following:

```
                              Table "Cyberpunk2020.Attributes"
  Column  |  Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description
----------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 Attr     | "Attr" |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 name     | text   |           |          |         | extended |              |
 Modifies | text[] |           |          |         | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "Attributes_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("Attr")
Child tables: public."Attributes"
Access method: heap
```

The Skills Table Like This:

```
\d+ "Skills"
                                  Table "Cyberpunk2020.Skills"
    Column    |  Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description
--------------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 Attribute    | "Attr" |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 Name         | text   |           | not null |         | extended |              |
 Desciption   | text   |           |          |         | extended |              |
 IPMultiplier | bigint |           |          | 1       | plain    |              |
 Modifies     | text[] |           |          |         | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "Skills_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("Attribute", "Name")
Child tables: public."Skills"
Access method: heap
```

Postgres version

```
                                                          version
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 13.9 (Debian 13.9-0+deb11u1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Thanks in Advance for all pointers in the right direction, as I am thoroughly confused.

I am expecting the Function to loop over the given text array `p_SkList` and insert the found names with the corrosponding Attribute as a new Row into "Skills"

Comment: The syntax is `IN ARRAY array_expr`, not `IN array_expr`.

Comment: Just unnest the array and you don’t need a loop. You don’t need plpgsql either, SQL would be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

> The syntax is IN ARRAY array_expr, not IN array_expr. –
> Laurenz Albe

That's all that was wrong, thank you very much, i feel pretty blind now ^^

This Code works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AddSkFromList(p_Attr "Cyberpunk2020"."Attr", p_SkList text[]) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    v_SkName text;
BEGIN
    FOREACH v_SkName IN ARRAY p_SkList LOOP
        INSERT INTO "Cyberpunk2020"."Skills" ("Attribute", "Name")
        VALUES (p_Attr, v_SkName);


    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not really an answer to the question. Please update your answer to include the changes required to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, using UNNEST() to get all items from the array. This avoids the loop and you don't need plpgsql either:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AddSkFromList(p_Attr "Cyberpunk2020"."Attr", p_SkList text[]) 
RETURNS void 
LANGUAGE sql;
AS 
$$
    INSERT INTO "Cyberpunk2020"."Skills" ("Attribute", "Name")
    SELECT  p_Attr
        ,   v_SkName
    FROM    UNNEST(p_SkList) AS sub(v_SkName);
$$;
```